# Issue with whitespace on top of keyboard on Safari Mobile

Tags: css, keyboard, height, mobile-safari

I've been having issues on Safari mobile where after focusing on an input element and opening the keyboard, a strip of white space was being added on top of the keyboard.

It was also breaking the styles of my application because the 'height: 100%' no longer worked and the elements were not adapting back to fill the entire height of the device after the keyboard has been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that solved this problem was making sure that all parent containers have a height of 100% (including html, body etc.) and then making sure that the scrollable container/ the last element that wraps the whole page has the following styles:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Make sure that these styles are only applied to mobile viewports as it might affect your desktop styling.